# Query for getting Cumulative sum up to certain number while getting total sum of another column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query in PHP that searches the database (By date, Desc) getting the Sum of the `Cost` Column until the cumulative sum of the `Quantity` column reaches a certain number.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Sum(Cost), Sum(Quantity) FROM Table UNTIL cumulative_total of (Quantity) <= 1000 WHERE Product='myProduct' ORDER BY `Date` Desc;
```

I thought this might work, but it returns no results:

```
SELECT Quantity, Cost, (@csum := @csum + Quantity) as cumulative_sum FROM Orders WHERE Product='selectedProduct' HAVING @csum <= '1500' ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

The purpose is that I want to be able to get the Average cost (Cost/Quantity) of recent entries in the database, but the Quantity will be a user-generated variable.

UPDATE:
Here is an example of the table structure:

| ID | Product | Quantity | Cost | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fork | 10 | 5.00 | 2022-04-19 |
| 2 | Fork | 10 | 5.00 | 2022-04-19 |
| 3 | Knife | 7 | 5.00 | 2022-04-20 |
| 4 | Fork | 20 | 10.00 | 2022-04-20 |
| 5 | Fork | 10 | 5.00 | 2022-04-21 |

If I wanted to know the average cost of the last 30 Forks, How would I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could include a sample data in an online database fiddle.
However please do try this

`SELECT *, @running_sum:=@running_sum+Quantity AS cumulativeSum FROM ( SELECT * FROM Orders o WHERE o.Product = 'selectedProduct' )a, (SELECT @running_sum:=0)rn ORDER BY DATE DESC;`

Comment: The code runs, but it gets all results instead of stopping once the cumulativeSum reaches a defined number.

Comment: This should work:
`SELECT *, (CASE WHEN  @running_sum>=19 THEN 0 ELSE @running_sum:=@running_sum+Quantity END) AS cumulativeSum FROM (
SELECT * FROM Orders o
WHERE o.Product = 'selectedProduct'  )a,
(SELECT @running_sum:=0)rn
WHERE @cumulativeSum<1500
ORDER BY DATE DESC`

Comment: It returned no results as well. I updated my question to include an example table and to clarify what I am ultimately looking to retreive.

Comment: Maybe this helps?
`SELECT cumulativeSum/(SUM(Quantity)) AS averageCose FROM (SELECT *,@running_sum:=@running_sum+Quantity    AS cumulativeSum 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM Orders o WHERE o.Product = 'Fork'  )a, 
(SELECT @running_sum:=0)rn  
ORDER BY date DESC) final
WHERE cumulativeSum<=30`

Comment: This worked with a minor adjustment: `SELECT SUM(Total)/cumulativeSum AS avg_cost FROM (SELECT *,@running_sum:=@running_sum+Quantity AS cumulativeSum FROM ( SELECT * FROM Orders o WHERE o.Product = 'Fork' )a, (SELECT @running_sum:=0)rn ORDER BY Date DESC) final WHERE cumulativeSum<=30` This worked when the `Quantity` was <=30, but returns null when the quantity queryed was lower (9 for example) so I created a php loop to check if the result was null, and if so, I ran a new query to grab just the last Entry. Thanks!